# Coda 2 erases my database on connection

Tags: mysql, database, coda

I have this annoying thing with Coda 2 on Mac OSX where whenever I connect to my MYSQL Database remotely, my database gets erased. Please I want to fix this because it's annoying me and I'm not really happy with it. Also Coda 2 doesn't have a Contact Us support so this would be my only way to ask this question. Thank you for reading.

Comment: https://www.panic.com/coda/support.html

Comment: Dont connect with root. Use a user with limited rights always.

Comment: I do, I created my own user but it still does the same thing. I believe the privileges are the same as root than as the new user I created